# How to access variable value outside of function and class in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

In following snippet would like to access value from outside of function and class

```
  driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(path)), 2000).
        then(text => {
               text.getText().then(value => {
                        console.log("value:: " + value);
                     })
```

Would like to access value from outside the function and class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: how to convert above mention code ?

Answer (score 0):

In promise `then()` chain, the return value in the last `then()` will be recognized as the value of the whole `then()` chai. Therefore you need to return `getText()` in the last `then()` as following:

```
var textPromise = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(path)), 2000)
    .then(target => {
        return target.getText(); // return getText() in last then()
    });
```

Then you can consume the promise value via `then()` on the promise as following:

```
// to use the text at outside via then()
textPromise.then((text)=>{
    console.log('text: ' + text);
});
```